# Recursive Function in JavaScript - Not calling it correctly

Tags: javascript

Can someone help explain to me what I am doing wrong on this recursive function?
I am attempting to pass in a value and if that value exists in my list of options, return it. If it is not available, then I want to subtract 10000 and try again until I find my matching value. It's pretty much working, except when I find my matching value, it doesn't seem to update on the original function call, maybe? Not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var totalCost = 34000,
    options = [10000, 0],
    recAmt;

if (totalCost >= 30000) {
    recAmt = getRecAmt(30000, 1);
    console.log(recAmt);
}

function getRecAmt(value, tier) {
    console.log('Trying: ' + value + ' for ' + tier);
    var i2 = 0,
        recAmt = 0;

    for (i2 = 0; i2 < options.length; i2 += 1) {
        if (value === parseInt(options[i2])) {
            recAmt = value;
            console.log('Found: ' + recAmt);
        }
    }

    if(recAmt === 0) {
        if (tier === 1) {
            getRecAmt(value - 10000, tier);
        }

    } else {
        return recAmt;
    }
}
```

Currently my console returns

```
Trying: 30000 for 1
Trying: 20000 for 1
Trying: 10000 for 1
Found: 10000
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything

```
if(recAmt === 0) {
    if (tier === 1) {
        getRecAmt(value - 10000, tier);
    }

} else {
    return recAmt;
}
```

needs to be

```
if(recAmt === 0) {
    if (tier === 1) {
        // RETURN STATEMENT HERE
        return getRecAmt(value - 10000, tier); 
    }

} else {
    return recAmt;
}
```

---

Here's a snippet to demonstrate

```js
var totalCost = 34000,
    options = [10000, 0],
    recAmt;

if (totalCost >= 30000) {
    recAmt = getRecAmt(30000, 1);
    console.log(recAmt);
}

function getRecAmt(value, tier) {
    console.log('Trying: ' + value + ' for ' + tier);
    var i2 = 0,
        recAmt = 0;

    for (i2 = 0; i2 < options.length; i2 += 1) {
        if (value === parseInt(options[i2])) {
            recAmt = value;
            console.log('Found: ' + recAmt);
        }
    }

    if(recAmt === 0) {
        if (tier === 1) {
            return getRecAmt(value - 10000, tier);
        }

    } else {
        return recAmt;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP can also get rid of one of the `if` statements to say `if(recAmt === 0 && tier === 1)`

Comment: @Adjit - That would give a different result, albeit at the moment there is the chance that this method could return `undefined` from thismethod (when `recAmt === 0` but `tier` is not 1).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. I made an edit to my original post to show what my console is logging. If (recAmt === 0) I am recalling my function and don't care about the value yet. I only care about it when a match is found, then I want that value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Nick what is your desired output?

Comment: @Adjit 10000 is what I'm wanting returned from my original call: recAmt = getRecAmt(30000, 1);

Comment: @Nick - The nature of a recursive function means that you *always* want to return the result of the next recursion, should the next recursion call itself, you want that result returned up the call chain. Try it with the change I described in this answer and see if it gives your expected output.